# How to add views dynamically to a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have an app in which I have a listview with custom text and image. what I want based on data model I want to increase the number of image view in a listview.How do I do that with a listview.

Comment: did you google, one google search gives you plenty of things to start: 
https://www.google.de/search?q=dynamically+listview+in+android+examples&oq=dynamicall+list+view+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.6607j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: add item to array and just do notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Add a list view say "x"
the layout which defines each item of the listview (in your case text and image) , in place of image add another listview say "y" (can be horizontal/vertical)
now have multiple images mapped to y using baseAdaptor.